# linear equation with conditions in Java

Tags: linear-programming, java

I have the following problem:
I want to determine a linear equation for a data table with $x$ and $y$ value. Point 1 should be the point where the first time $y > 0$ and point 2 should be the point where the last time $y < 1$. The linear equation is then to be generated between points 1 and 2. For example in the table between point $x = 2$ and $x = 4$. In addition the x-values are written in an array, the y-values are imported from an excel-file.
At the end I want so save the parameters of the linear equation.

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 0.1 |
| 3 | 0.4 |
| 4 | 0.95 |
| 5 | 1.1 |
| 6 | 0.9 |

Comment: So you want a line connecting the points (2,0.1) and (4,0.95), and the rest of the points are ignored? if that is not the case, you need to explain more clearly.

Comment: @Handballer73, are you trying to do something like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/udas0z8xodimtqr/test.jpg?dl=0)?

Comment: Yes, the other points can be ignored...